# Determing line number and file name of the perl file from within C++

Tags: c++, perl, xs

I am working with Perl embedded in our application.  We have installed quite a few C++ functions that are called from within Perl.  One of them is a logging function.  I would like to add the file name and line number of the Perl file that called this function to the log message.
I know on the Perl side I can use the "caller()" function to get this information, but this function is already used in hundreds of locations, so I would prefer to modify the C++ side, is this information passed to the C++ XSUB functions and if so how would I get at it?

Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This should work:

```
char *file;
I32 line;

file = OutCopFILE(PL_curcop);
line = CopLINE(PL_curcop);
```

> Control ops (cops) are one of the two ops OP_NEXTSTATE and op_DBSTATE,
>   that (loosely speaking) are separate statements.
>   They hold information important for lexical state and error reporting.
>   At run time, PL_curcop is set to point to the most recently executed cop,
>   and thus can be used to determine our current state.

— cop.h

Answer (score 1):

Can't you call perl builtins from XS? I confess I don't know.

If not, you could always do something like this:

```
sub logger { _real_logger(caller, @_) }
```

assuming `logger` is what your function is called (and you rename your C++ XS function to `_real_logger`. You could also do this, presumably, if you need to hide yourself in the call tree:

```
sub logger {
    unshift @_, caller;
    goto &_real_logger;
}
```

which is of course the normal form of goto used in `AUTOLOAD`.

These will add overhead, of course, but probably not a big deal for a logging function.

Comment: The functions are installed in a namespace called "out" from c++, it is referenced everywhere via out::debug, I do not know if I can install a perl function within the same namespace though.  The overhead would be of little concern, really only want it for debugging.